Free library to create, merge, and modify PDF documents
I know that this question has been asked before, but the previous answers don't seem to be recent enough that the answers are valid or relevant any longer.
The organization I work for currently has two licensed products that we use to deal with PDFs. As the licensing fees are getting very insane, they have asked me to look into finding a single solution, free or open source preferably, that we could convert over to that would take care of our needs.
The solution would have to be able to handle the following functionality:

Convert an incoming Base64 encoded byte stream into a PDF
Merge multiple byte streams into a single document.
Add a custom stamp to the PDF (think like a Filed ink stamp a clerk would use to indicate that paper work has been processed. Needs to be custom so that a date and clerk name could be added to it on the fly)

I've been looking into PDFSharp. It looks like it might be able to handle what we would need. The problem is that the documentation is so bad that I'm not even able to make the examples work. I don't know if that is because the APIs don't work with .NET 8 or for some other reason that I am missing. There aren't any tutorials that I can find that might help me understand if I was making any mistakes.
Does anyone know of a solution that they could point me in the direction of? It can be a paid solution, but the licensing needs to be straightforward and not on a per-project basis.
Thanks!

"has been asked before" - please link the questions you have already considered.

You can try Syncfusion PDF framework

Create, read, and edit PDF files with just a few lines of code.
Convert 20+ of the most common and popular document formats to PDF.
View and review PDF files seamlessly in your apps.

https://www.syncfusion.com/document-processing/pdf-framework/net
Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense
Note: I work for Syncfusion

Windows CMD with a few files will (you will need to use windows tar.exe to unpack the zips)

decode base64 filestream (b64.exe -d input output)
may look old but perfectly good 10 years later (a favourite) https://sourceforge.net/projects/base64/files/
merge multiple pdf into one (pdfunite [options] <PDF-sourcefile-1>..<PDF-sourcefile-n> <PDF-destfile>)
https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases/tag/v24.07.0-0
or see next can also merge.
Add a custom stamp to the PDF pdfcpu stamp options https://pdfcpu.io/core/stamp

Done well thats 2 or 3 lines of code in a CMD shell
or they all provide open sources for "roll your own"

The Spire.PDF for .NET library provides the features you mentioned. You can request a free trial license and test it thoroughly.
Here is the documentation of the library for your reference:
https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide-Content.html

The PDF4NET library supports all your requirements.
Evaluation version is available for download. 
The samples are available on GitHub: https://github.com/o2solutions/pdf4net
Our support team will answer any question you might have about the library.
Note: I work for the company that develops PDF4NET
